# Access dictionary key value in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access into a dictionary values inside of an array and I'm not able to access those values by key. Any solution?

```
const extracted_data = [
  { adv: 'ADD UP', mean: 'totalizar' },
  { adv: 'ADD UP TO', mean: 'alcanzar un total' },
  { adv: 'ASK UP TO', mean: 'pedir hasta (un precio)' },
  { adv: 'ASK UP', mean: 'invitar a subir' },
  { adv: 'BACK UP', mean: 'reforzar' }
]

for (let i=0; i < extracted_data.length; i++) {
    console.log(extracted_data[i][adv])
  }
```

[image]

Comment: `console.log(extracted_data[i]["adv"])` you need to use a  string for the key identifier.

Comment: Solved. Thanks! @ptothep

Answer (score 2):

your comptued attribute should be `string`; you are passing a non-exist variable

```
for (let i=0; i < extracted_data.length; i++) {
    console.log(extracted_data[i]["adv"])
  }
```